# How to use echo command to show '?

Tags: command-line

for example I want to echo :

```
  "let vim know the last edit position
  au BufReadPost * if line("'\"") > 0|if line("'\"")
  \ <= line("$")|exe("norm '\"")|else|exe "norm $"|endif|endif
```

I tried but failed:

```
  echo '
  "let vim know the last edit position
  au BufReadPost * if line("\'\"") > 0|if line("\'\"")
  \ <= line("$")|exe("norm \'\"")|else|exe "norm $"|endif|endif
  '
```

How to show the correct format?

Thank you~

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [here documents](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/here-docs.html):

```
cat <<-EOF
  au BufReadPost * if line("'\"") > 0|if line("'\"")
  \ <= line("$")|exe("norm '\"")|else|exe "norm $"|endif|endif
EOF
```

Comment: I was going to answer the best I could do is to use cat rather then echo.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use `echo`, all you need to do is to use single quotes

```
'string containing many strange characters $ " \ and so'
```

The only problem is posed by literal single quotes contained in the string.
In such a case:

1. close the string before the literal `'`
2. write and escaped single quote `\'`
3. reopen the string to continue with following characters

For example:

```
aaa'bbb  ==>  'aaa' + \' + 'bbb'  ==>  'aaa'\''bbb'
```

Obviously, if the literal single quote is at the start or end of the string, one of the closing or opening quote should not be used:

```
'aaa'bbb  ==>  \' + 'aaa' + \' + 'bbb'  ==>  \''aaa'\''bbb'
```

Your specific string can be output with the command

```
echo '"let vim know the last edit position
au BufReadPost * if line("'\''\"") > 0|if line("'\''\"")
\ <= line("$")|exe("norm '\''\"")|else|exe "norm $"|endif|endif'
```