# How to use ' and " (quotes) as an argument

Tags: bash, gnome-terminal

**Intro**

In a script I want to run a command in a separate window so that output of the command will show in a new window (which is an output stream like `top`) and they do not interfere each other. For this I use `gnome-terminal -x bash -c 'command'`.
For example: `"\` can be printed using `gnome-terminal -x bash -c 'echo "\"\\";    read '` or `gnome-terminal -x bash -c 'echo -e "\x22\x5c"; read '`. I just don't interested in *hexadecimal* as it will not work with other command than `echo`.

**Question**

How can I print `"'`?
Executing `gnome-terminal -x bash -c 'echo "\"\'";    read '`
Is there any alternative to `gnome-terminal -x bash -c` to run a command in a new window ? (Not in background).

**My case**

```
gnome-terminal -x bash -c 'perl -le 'open(P,"sudo nethogs lo |");  $|=1;
while(<P>){ print "------","$_"; }'  >> /tmp/a.txt'`
```

What I do currently is

1. Assign perl code to a variable  `cmd_perl='open(P,"sudo nethogs ppp0 |");  $|=1;  while(<P>){ print "------","$_"; }'`
2. save to a file   `echo "$cmd_perl" > "/tmp/cmd_perl.pl"`
3. execute it in bash pointing file  `gnome-terminal -x  bash -c 'perl /tmp/cmd_perl.pl  >> /tmp/nethogs-dump-from-perl.hex '`
   This method works fine. I want to avoid the use of temp file.

[How to use echo command to show '?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/99452/how-to-use-echo-command-to-show) doesn't answer my question.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
bash -c "echo \'"
```

or

```
bash -c "echo \"'\""
```

Combining it:

```
$ bash -c 'echo "\"\\"'"\'"
"\'
```

Comment: case 1: Works OK but I want to print both `'` and `"`. ie `'"`

Comment: How about the 3rd example?  The first part ( `'echo "\"\\"'` ) uses single quotes, the second part ( `"\'"` ) uses double quotes.

Comment: case 2 : can only print `'`

Comment: case 3: terminal wait for something like end quote

Comment: case 3: I think bash has access until `bash -c 'echo "\"\\"'"\'` and rest of the code (`"\'"
"\'`) not executed by bash.

Comment: There should be no spaces between the quoted segments, they should be "glued" together.

Comment: case 3: I copy pasted your cmd. If I preserve *new line*, it waits for something else print `"\'`

Comment: I tried a number of bash shells on various OS and everywhere `bash -c 'echo "\"\\"'"\'"` prints `"\'`. That does not work in your case? What do you mean with "preserve newline" ?

Comment: In case 3, cmd is in 2 lines. In your above comment it's in 1 line.  `bash -c 'echo "\"\\"'"\'"` prints `"\'`. I can't understand how your cmd works. Could u pls explain it or do the trick on *my case* (See my question's my case)